# clisp: encoding and decoding character sets without file I/O

Tags: encoding, utf-8, clisp

Suppose I have a byte vector containing data encoded using, say, utf-8 (though I won't the name of the encoding until run time).  How do I decode that into a string of characters?

One way is to use `#'ext:write-byte-sequence` to output the data to a file and then turn around and open the file with :external-format charset:utf-8.  But is there a way to do this without a scratch file?

**EDIT 204-03-25 21:48:00 UTC**

As required by ancient solemn custom, I hereby pay to **sds** [image: one zorkmid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[31.5.7. Converting between strings and byte vectors](http://clisp.org/impnotes/encoding.html#string-byte)

Encodings can also be used to convert directly between strings and their corresponding byte vector representation according to that encoding.

```
(EXT:CONVERT-STRING-FROM-BYTES vector encoding &KEY :START :END)
```

converts the subsequence of vector (a (`VECTOR (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8))`) from start to end to a STRING, according to the given encoding, and returns the resulting string.

```
(EXT:CONVERT-STRING-TO-BYTES string encoding &KEY :START :END)
```

converts the subsequence of string from start to end to a `(VECTOR (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8))`, according to the given encoding, and returns the resulting byte vector.

[You now owe me 1 zorkmid. :-)](http://clisp.org/impnotes/faq.html#faq-fine)

Comment: Indeed I do.  This is embarrassing.  I stared at that document until I was blue in the face, going back and forth several times.  Payment has been edited into the original question.